# javascript confirm doesnt work on latest chrome 31

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo

JavaScript Confirm or alert doest work on latest chrome(chrome 31).

I have an application where my application opens another browser window and alert, confirm doesn't work on that.

This use to work fine in old chrome. Now, The confirm window opens with "OK" and "Cancel" button, but the content doesn't get displayed at all.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you share your code using a fiddle ?

Comment: I am using 32, and it works http://jsfiddle.net/GzRpF/. Have you seen official bug for this on google chrome project page? Finally, provide your code http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: On Chrome 31 stable, it's working fine from the console. Your problem might be related to some other code, not the `alert` or `confirm` functions itself.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the response.
Yes..On the main page of the application, The alert and confirm works fine. when I open another window(mainly for download)from my application, there alert or confirm wont work in latest browser.The confirm/alert pop up opens with empty content.